# In Mann's six-functor formalism, do diagrams with the forget-supports map commute?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, cohomology, etale-cohomology, six-operations

One of the main goals in formalizing six-functor formalisms is to obtain some sort of "coherence theorem", affirming that "every diagram that should commute, commutes". In [these lecture notes](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/SixFunctors.pdf), Scholze explains one approach to this problem in which "every diagram arising from proper base change or the projection formula commutes".

In the sixth lecture, Scholze constructs natural transformations $f_!\to f_*$ (notably, for "separated" $f$) and $g^!\to g^*$ (notably, when $g$ is an "immersion"). **Is it true that diagrams constructed using these maps also commute? What about diagrams using (co)units of the many adjunctions in a six-functor formalism?**

Let me give a, possibly minimal, example. Consider the cartesian diagram below

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
X' @>g'>> X \\
@Vf'VV @VVfV \\
S' @>>g> S,
\end{CD}$$

where $f$ and $g$ are as above. We can then construct the following diagram whose maps are either those above or isomorphisms arising from proper base change.

$$\begin{CD}
g^! f_! @>>> g^! f_* @>\sim>> f'_* g^{\prime,!} \\
@VVV @. @VVV \\
g^* f_! @>\sim>> f'_! g^{\prime,*} @>>> f'_* g^{\prime,*}.
\end{CD}$$

Does it necessarily commute? If so, why?

Comment: These natural transformations come from base change formulas and units and counits of the usual adjunctions (for example, that's why separatedness comes in for $f_! \to f_*$, so that you have a unit $id \to \Delta_!\Delta^*$ where $\Delta$ is the diagonal). So if you unravel the definitions this kind of commutativity is tautological. This goes back to SGA, it doesn't really have anything to do with Mann's formalism or any of the other $\infty$-categorical ones, which are rather trying to capture some higher homotopy coherence of these diagrams.

Comment: @crystalline In what sense does this go back to SGA? I have looked a few times for similar but simpler results in SGA and I don't think I've seen them in there. The fact that base change isomorphisms are involved means this can't be fully formal / categorical and has to involve the definition of the base change map. One strategy of proof is to go back to the definitions but that leads a lot to be desired, for example because it doesn't generalize well to more difficult (including higher categorical) settings.

Comment: So it's better to prove these things by deducing from some general formalism, of which Mann's is the best (and almost the only relevant) one available. I wouldn't be surprised if in some sense it's tautological but technically everything we do is (surely the higher categorical coherences, understood properly, are tautological too) and the question is just how to check it. In summary, you should write an answer explaining how to use the adjunctions to check this!

Comment: It might be a naive comment, but this paper of Josefien Kuijer could help answering your question: https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.11449

Comment: The good reference for checking these kinds of commutativity is written in the first and second chapter of J. Ayoub, Les six operations de Grothendieck et le formalisme des cycles évanescents dans le monde motivique. A quick glance at your diagram makes me think that its commutativity should follow from Corollaire 1.1.14 in loc.cit.

Comment: Dear Damien, I took a look in this paper but I don't see how it can help here. Dear Alexey, it seems impossible to prove that my diagram (or any related one) commutes without using specifically the compatibilities hidden in the span category and the definition of the forget-supports maps. How do you suggest that we use the corollary that you mentioned?

Comment: I'm happy to write an answer, but do you mind explaining what difficulty you're facing if you just unravel the definitions? (Don't mind Sawin's comment, if you know anything about encoding 6ff's using correspondence categories then you know base change isomorphisms are baked into the data as a starting point.) The proof amounts to writing a big commutative diagram and observing that you have a bunch of tautologically commuting subsquares, and this kind of thing is not very easy to explain on this website.

Comment: Dear @crystalline, I am familiar with using correspondences to prove that diagrams involving base change and projection formulas commute. However, it's not clear to me that diagrams involving (co)units of the adjunctions commute. (And the construction of $f_!\to f_*$ uses many such (co)units.) Even supposing this to be true, I am also a little confused with the fact that the construction of the forget-supports map is done by induction on the $n$ such that $f$ is $n$-truncated.